# IONIC MSAL wrapper import { Msal } from 'ionic-msal-native'; signout not working

Tags: iphone, ionic-framework

Problem :

```
import { Msal } from 'ionic-msal-native'; 


public  logout(accountId: string,
    successCallback: (result: any) => any,
  errorCallback: (message: string) => any
): 
void {
     this.msal.signOut(accountId).then(successCallback,errorCallback);
}
```

The above function not working to clear cache of browser when we logout from mobile application in IONIC Cordova hybrid app.

In IOS IONIC its navigate to continue screen and not to prompt user to enter username and PASS.

Any help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.